# Ruby variables visibility inside modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

**TL;DR;**
I need to make some @@vars of a static method (extends) in one module visible to a instance method in another module(includes).

How to accomplish that once only setting @@var=value was not enough to make it visible?

Maybe you can just read my capitalized comment bellow and jump to question 4.

---

Hi, I would like to add an method to my models to index some data in a mysql table with some full text search fields.

In order to accomplish that, I created the following module:

```
module ElasticFakeIndexing

  module IndexingTarget

    #instance method to be called on model to get data to save
    def build_index_data
      {
        entity_id: self.id, 
        entity_type: self.class.name, 

        #UNABLE TO ACCESS IF SET ONLY WITH @@var=value. Why?
        #AND ALMOST SURE THAT USING class_variable_set IS THE CAUSE OF CONFIGURATION OF ONE MODULE MESSING UP WITH ANOTHER'S
        title: @@title_fields.collect{|prop| self.send(prop.to_sym)}.join(" || "), 
        description: @@description_fields.collect{|prop| self.send(prop.to_sym)}.join(" || "),
      }
    end

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods

      #class method to declare/call at a given model
      def elastic_fake(options = {})
        #Make sure we always get an array so we can use 'join'
        title_arg = Array(options[:title])
        ElasticFakeIndexing::IndexingTarget.class_variable_set(:@@title_fields, title_arg)
        description_arg = Array(options[:description])
        ElasticFakeIndexing::IndexingTarget.class_variable_set(:@@description_fields, description_arg)
        extra_arg =  Array(options[:extra])
        ElasticFakeIndexing::IndexingTarget.class_variable_set(:@@extra_args, extra_arg)

      end

    end

  end

end
```

And I use it this way at my models:

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  #includes the module
  include ElasticFakeIndexing::IndexingTarget

  ...

  # 'static' method call to configure to all classes of this model
  elastic_fake(title: "prop_a", description: ["prop_b", "prop_c", "prop_d"])
end
```

And at some point of my code something like this will be called:

```
index_data = some_model_instance.build_index_data
save_on_mysql_text_search_fields(index_data)
```

But I got some problems. And have some questions:

1. when I use/include my module in a second model, looks like the configuration of one model is being visible to the other. And I got 'invalid fields' like errors. I guess it happens because of this, for example:
   ElasticFakeIndexing::IndexingTarget.class_variable_set(:@@title_fields, title_arg)
2. But I got to this this because only set @@title_fields wasn't enough to make title_fields visible at build_index_data instance method. Why?
3. Why using only @title_fields isn't enough too to make it visible at build_index_data?
4. How to design it in a way that the set of fields are set in a 'static' variable for each model, and visible inside the instance method build_index_data? Or as a possible solution, the fields could live in a instance variable and be visible. But I think it should live in a 'static' variable because the fields will not change from one instance of the model to another...

Any thoughts? What am I missing about the variables scopes/visibility?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read the following articles on Ruby variables:

- [Ruby Variable Scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope)
- [Understanding Scope in Ruby](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/)

quick reminder: `@@title_fields`, class variable, must be initialized at creation time, while `@title_fields`, instance variable, hasn't such requirement.

Comment: Thanks. The last one I read before posting. I will read again... But I`m still missing why @@var got the same for all including classes (so, I got 'invalid field' errors) instead of becoming available for each including class. If I understood correctly, @@var was created and maintained inside the "InnerModule", therefore, was shared to all. Is it what happened? I got this right? Is there a way to make one @@var to each including class?

Comment: "Must be initialized at creation time" means I need to do something in my including class? It includes the module, class de class method, and inside this class method @@var should be set. Is it ok as "initialize at creation time"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on class variables I recommend using class side instance variables. Class variables will easily be overwritten between individual models including the module. Class side instance variables however are save.

Using some of the syntactic sugar (namely [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and [class_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute)) rails offers you could write something like

```
module ElasticFakeIndexing
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :title_fields, 
                    :description_fields,
                    :extra_args
  end

  class_methods do
    def elastic_fake(options = {})
      ...
      self.title_fields = Array(options[:title])
      ...
    end
  end

  def build_index_data
    ...
    title: self.class.title_fields ...
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: This "thing" with class_attribute reminds (the idea) me of the way (wrong) I tried with just '@'var. I will try to modify my code to match yours and see what happens. But, '@'var var shouldn't be made available inside my including object? Or @@var made visible just like class_attribute?

Comment: You will not be able to make the `@@var` (class variables) available in the including class' instances directly. `@var` (instance  variables) you can access but you will not be able to assign values to it via a class method.   
Strictly speaking you could wrap the class variable inside a class method e.g. `def text_fields @@text_fields end` and access it via `self.class.text_fields` in an instance but this would leave you with the problem of one including class overriding the values of another's including class.